# VBA code to select the range of last column and row

Tags: vba, excel

Solved. I've been looking for code that would allow you to select the range of last column and last row within a spreadsheet. After doing some digging and using some logic, I was able to come up with a solution. First, I defined the last Row using the following:

```
LR = Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row and then I used the following to define last column 

LC= wcolNm(colNum)

Public function LC= wcolNm(colNum)

ColNum = Cells(1 & columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
wcolumn = split(cells(1, column).address, "$")(1)
End function
```

The end state looks as followed:

```
Range("A" & 1 & ":" & LC & LR).select
```

Which I inserted after LC. My apologies if this is confusing but I'm new to coding and was looking for this code for a while so I felt like it would be good to post. I'll give more details if needed.

Comment: You can ask the question here and then post an answer. I think this has likely been answered before though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I typically do it.

```
Range(Cells(1, Columns.Count), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Select
```

You don't typically want to use the UsedRange method of selecting cells if your data changes at all.

Comment: The down-side with End(xlUp) is that it doesn't "see" hidden rows.

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about hidden rows as far as I know :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can do this in an easier way. Provided you are attempting to select your entire range of data (i.e. A1 to your last row and column), you can use the following method:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
ws.UsedRange.Select
```

That should select all of your data. This is also assuming you're working with the first worksheet.

Comment: There is a problem with this method.  If he used a cell in the past that's outside of the current range, it will select all the way out to said cell.